# WooCommerce Opayo Payment Suite - programmatically change payment to deferred or authenticate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to the world of WooCommerce, so please bear with me :-)

We have WooCommerce installed and we also have the Opayo Payment Suite plugin installed so that we can take payments using our Opayo account.

What we need to do is thus:

A) If the order has an up-front payment, then we want to set the transaction to "Take payment immediately", which is actually the default setting.

B) However, if the order does not contain any up-front payments, then we only need to verify the customer so we need to programmatically set the transaction to "Authenticate only".

I can't seem to find any hooks or filters to be able to do this.

I hope there is someone out there who has experience with this and can help me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to contact the authors of Opayo Payment Suite plugin...

Comment: I did - but they're not very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to confirm with Opayo that authenticate and authorise is enabled on your account

Comment: That's already taken care of.